# Am I correctly forming this multidimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

Here I attempt to create a matrix, by assigning arrays to a pointer reference:

```
bb_ANN(int num_Weights, int num_Layers, int num_Nodes, double * inputs){

//create an array that will hold pointers
struct ANN_Node *layer[num_Layers];
//create an array of nodes
struct ANN_Node **arr = malloc(sizeof(struct ANN_Node **) *num_Layers);
//initialize Nodes
for(int i=0;i<num_Layers;i++)
{       
    // layer heads
    layer[i] = ANN_Init_Node(num_Weights); 
    for(int j=0; j<num_Nodes;j++)
    //push nodes into each layer head
    { push_ANN_Node(&layer[i],num_Weights); }
    // converting each list into an array, then each embedding into arr[] 
     arr[i] = arrayOfList(layer[i]); 
}


    printf("f(x):%f ", arr[0][1].weights[0]);
////////////
```

This is the arrayOfList definition :

```
struct ANN_Node *arrayOfList(struct ANN_Node *listP){
int i = lengthOfList(listP) ; //make i the length of the list
struct ANN_Node **ptr=  malloc(sizeof(struct ANN_Node **) *i);
for(i=0;listP != NULL;listP=listP->next,i++)
{ ptr[i] = listP; }
return ptr;
    }
```

Now  what I am attempting to do, is to make a sort of matrix of 'ANN_Nodes' :

```
-->[ 0 0 0 ]
-->[ 0 0 0 ]
-->[ 0 0 0 ]
```

whereby, I create a loop which goes through each layer and inserts an array that my arrayOfList function would return.

Now there's this resulting thing:
`arr[0][0].weights[0]` and this is fine.
So is this `arr[1][0].weights[0]` and this `arr[2][0].weights[0]` etcetera.

But I have failed to actually create something two dimensional : `arr[0][1].weights[0]` this is a failure and a segfault.

Does what I am attempting to do make sense, is it feasible, and how might I actually achieve a two dimensional array structure so that I can carry on with my purposes ?

PS. I have checked out multidimensional arrays already but I think my case is a bit different from the majority of examples and tutorials I find on the internet, I am trying to sort of inject a returned array into and array of arrays if that makes sense...

Comment: `sizeof(struct ANN_Node *)` gives you the size of a pointer (which is architecture dependant). If you want the size of the struct, use `sizeof(struct ANN_Node)`

Comment: In C you [don't have to cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I suppose so. I've read some arguments on this site however, both for and against the casting thing, the way I understood it, it seemed the pro's for casting, is that its more generalisable in some way that prevents some unique errors.
I took it as 'safer' and just kept doing it in the hope that it's good form.

Comment: Not casting should not create any problems, but casting *will* create problems if you forget to include the `<stdlib.h>` header file.

Comment: Is it even recommended to write a C program without including <stdlib.h> ? @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `arrayOfList` function you create an "array" of pointers, and make `ptr` point to that memory.

Then you do `return *ptr;` which is equal to `return ptr[0];`. That is, you return a single pointer to a single element. The rest of the "array" will be lost.

If you want a dynamic "2d array" of pointers in C you need to become a [three-star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer), as it will be (in your case) of type `struct ANN_Node ***`.

Then `arrayOfList` should return `struct ANN_Node **`, i.e. `ptr` (instead of `*ptr`).

Comment: wouldn't it be better to allocate a big block once(as the size is known at allocation) and then just access this correctly insteast of using a pointer to pointer to pointer construct?

Comment: @KamiKaze It's of course one solution. It kind of depends on use-case and other requirements and limitations (a single allocation of a big block might not be possible for large amounts of data).

Comment: I changed the array of List function to this : `struct ANN_Node **arrayOfList(struct ANN_Node *listP)
{
 int i = lengthOfList(listP) ; //make i the length of the list
 struct ANN_Node **ptr= (struct ANN_Node **) malloc(sizeof(struct ANN_Node) *i);
 for(i=0;listP != NULL;listP=listP->next,i++)
 { ptr[i] = listP; }
 return ptr;
}` But I still seem to get segfault.

Comment: @timi95 Now you're allocating the wrong size, probably to much. And did you remember to change the `bb_ANN` function accordingly?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yah, some one commented this  : "sizeof(struct ANN_Node *) gives you the size of a pointer (which is architecture dependant). If you want the size of the struct, use sizeof(struct ANN_Node)" .  So I changed it, I will revert back to what it was. What do I need to change with the assignment in bb_ANN ?

Comment: This was the solution !! :  ` //create an array of nodes
 struct ANN_Node ***arr = malloc(sizeof(struct ANN_Node **) *num_Layers);` . So now I am assigning an appropriate structure to 'arr' and my warnings are gone now. PS. Thank you, if you have anything to add about how I might avoid situations like this in future, I'd be very keen for such advice. @Someprogrammerdude